# (SPL-Token) Solana Create Token Account with Wallet Adapter | React, JS

Tags: spl-token, javascript, solana-wallet-adapter, anchor-spl

## Problem with solana-wallet-adapter

I am developing a Dapp with a token I created, I use the React Wallet Adapter provided by solana (`solana-wallet-adapter`). I am using javascript, but when I use the `getOrCreateTokenAccount()` method, I get an error. It is worth mentioning that I am sending the wallet address from the wallet adapter, but that is not `web3.keypair` but `WalletContextState`. I tried to send the transaction but it fails.

### Snippets of my code

Creating the token account.

```
async function createTokenAccount(){
    const minted = await getMint(connection,tokenContract)
    const tx = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
        connection,
        wallet,
        minted,
        wallet.publicKey);
    console.log(tx)
}
```

Resulting error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: mint.toBuffer is not a function
getAssociatedTokenAddress mint.ts:123
getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts:46
createTokenAccount conectWallet.js:78
React 23
js index.js:29
factory react refresh:6
Webpack 3
```

### Changes with the new code (Edit 1)

I made these changes with the suggestion. But now it gives the following error.

New code:

```
const mint = await getMint(connection, tokenContract);
const tx = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  wallet,
  mint.address,
  wallet.publicKey
);
```

Resulting error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TokenAccountNotFoundError: 
    TokenError errors.ts:4
    TokenAccountNotFoundError bundle.js:134630
    getAccount account.ts:93
```

Comment: Could you show the errors

Comment: This is the error 

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: mint.toBuffer is not a function
    getAssociatedTokenAddress mint.ts:123
    getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount.ts:46
    createTokenAccount conectWallet.js:78
    React 23
    js index.js:29
    factory react refresh:6
    Webpack 3`

Comment: You might consider deleting the Rust code in this question and posting it as a separate question so that this doesn’t get closed as ‘lacking focus.’

Comment: please update the post rather than post the error message as a comment. it's unreadable this way

Comment: Well there I put that I had edited (edit 1), the previous error is because of the comment that I was asked for the output. If you tell me what is illegible, I will gladly correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the account assigned to the token, in the wallet. For this use the following code:

```
const associatedAccount = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
            mint.address,
            wallet.publicKey
        )
```

Once, the account is stored. I had to create and send the transaction instruction.

```
 const createToken = new Transaction().add(
            createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                wallet.publicKey,
                associatedAccount,
                wallet.publicKey,
                mint.address
            )
        );
```

And that's it, all that's left is to approve the transaction in the wallet. Done, we have successfully added the token.

> One small note, depending on your wallet, it will show the token. In Phantom, it doesn't show it until you already have some amount in it, but solflare does show the token address.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `getMint` is a `Mint`. The third parameter of `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` is a `PublicKey`.

Change your invocation to this:

```
const mint = await getMint(connection, tokenContract);
const tx = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  wallet,
  mint.address,
  wallet.publicKey
);
```

Comment: Make sure that you enable the Typescript typechecker in your editor. It will point out errors like this one without you having to run the code.

Comment: In fact, I don’t think you need to `getMint` at all, because isn’t `tokenContract` the same as `mint.address` here?

Comment: Look at line 93 of `account.ts`: https://github.com/jordansexton/spl-token-js/blob/ee5e879ee36dc26bb55ecc48dda40f68cbd940cf/src/state/account.ts#L93

Matching up your input arguments, that implies that `wallet` does not exist. Either:

1. It does not exist, or
2. Your connection is pointing to the wrong cluster (eg. mainnet-beta, when in fact your account is on devnet).